# How to export variables named with hyphen in ESM

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

CJS

```
exports['foo-bar'] = {}  // -> OK
```

ESM

```
exports['foo-bar'] = {};        // -> NG
export['foo-bar'] = {};         // -> NG
export { 'foo-bar': {} };       // -> NG
export { fooBar as foo-bar };   // -> NG
export { fooBar as 'foo-bar' }; // -> NG
```

---

Normally I wouldn't do this, so it's not a problem, but I'm having trouble because [Firebase Functions v2 only allows lowercase alphabets, numbers and hyphens in the name](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta#other_limitations) and requires that I export it.

Comment: according to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) `export { fooBar as 'foo-bar' }` should work - visual studio code doesn't like it (in my case) but it definitely works

Comment: Thanks!!! It's definitely in the doc.
The error may just be around TS, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I knew it was on the TS side; TypeScript 4.7 did not support it.
Resolved. Thanks!
[Support “Arbitrary module namespace identifier names” · Issue #40594 · microsoft/TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40594)

Comment: Oh, how did you fix it (or, did you fix it?)

Comment: I've given up trying to fix it with using TS because it's not supported by TS4.7.
My solution is to not use TS. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: My solution is to use `export {fooBar as foobar}` for now and wait until TS supports dashes.

Comment: FYI, I've tried `exports['foo-bar'] = fooBar`, while there is no syntax error in vscode, it fails to deploy to cloud functions with `container-failed-to-start` error.

Answer (score 5):

What I found after ditching typescript to get

```
export { endpoint as "my-dashed-endpoint-name" }
```

I found that firebase still wouldn't let me call `my-dashed-endpoint-name`, giving me the error `Failed to find function my.dashed.endpoint.name in the loaded module`.. hmmm.

So what firebase *actually* wants you to do, is export an object, and it will turn the name into a dashed version of the object path!

So to get a function called `my-dashed-endpoint-name`, you'd have to do.

```
export let my = {
  dashed: {
    endpoint: {
      name: onCall(...),
    }
  }
}
```

Not the most ergonomic... but it does make a little more sense when using

```
export * as post from "./post-endpoints.js"
```

which would prefix all the exports from `post-endpoints.js` with `post-` (e.g. `post-delete`, `post-add`)

Comment: Not sure why, but if using this technique then `setGlobalOptions` then it will be ignored. For example `setGlobalOptions({ region: "australia-southeast1" });` will deploy to the default location of `us-central1` instead of `australia-southeast1"`. Same goes for when using the function provided by @foges in the other answer here.

Comment: Thank you!! Was stuck on this for so long.

Answer (score 0):

It's crazy to me that there isn't an easier way to do this. Nonetheless extending Michiel's answer to make it more re-usable:

```js
import { CallableFunction } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

function exportFn<T = any, Return = any | Promise<any>>(
  name: string,
  func: CallableFunction<T, Return>
) {
  const words = name.split("-");
  let target = exports;
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
    if (!target[words[i]]) {
      target[words[i]] = {};
    }
    target = target[words[i]];
  }
  target[words[words.length - 1]] = func;
}
```

You can then call it like

```
exportFn("my-firebase-function", myFirebaseFunction);
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `CallableFunction` type from? I tried `import { CallableFunction } from "firebase-functions/v2";` it doesnt work.

Comment: Almost. You need `import { CallableFunction } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";` Updated the post.