# How do I use dashes in the name of a Firebase Function V2

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am upgrading my firebase functions to v2.  Previously my functions were named using camel-case (e.g. doCoolStuff) and snake-case (e.g. dope_api).  But neither of these are supported in v2.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta#other_limitations

> Function names are restricted to lowercase letters, numbers, and dashes

The only way to specify the function name, that I'm aware of, is based on the exported name (I'm using typescript) and variable names with dashes aren't supported.

```
export const doCoolStuff = onRequest(...)
// or
export const dope_api = onRequest(...)
```

So how do I create a function with name that includes dashes, instead of the spaces I used before?

Comment: The question has already been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73452376/how-to-export-variables-named-with-hyphen-in-esm

Comment: FYI, I've tried `exports['do-cool-stuff'] = doCoolStuff`, while there is no syntax error in vscode, it fails to deploy to cloud functions with `container-failed-to-start` error.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this, the old answers in the link didn't work, here is how I finally got dashes/hyphens in the routes with V2 firebase-functions without needing express.

this produces the working endpoint of `say-hello`

```
const { onRequest } = require('firebase-functions/v2/https');

function say() {
    return { hello : sayHello }
}

var sayHello = onRequest(
    (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send("Hello, is it me you're looking for");
    }
);

exports["say"] = say();
```